# How to find the class of the Object supplied to a Consumer in an argument?

Tags: java, generics

I am making an event system with multiple types of events, eg `ExampleEvent extends Event`. I need to figure out which type of event I supplied to the hook function through a lambda/consumer, using the following syntax:

```
hook(
    (ExampleEvent e) -> e.example(),
    (ExampleEvent2 e) -> // code here
);
```

This is what I have so far, I need to add the consumers to a map so I can run them each time an event  is called. Is there any way I can make this work? Is there a better way I could do this?

```
static Map<Class, ArrayList<Consumer<? extends Event>>> hooks = new HashMap<>();

public static void hook(Consumer<? extends Event> ...consumers) {
    for(Consumer<? extends Event > fn : consumers) {
        final Class klass = // class supplied in lambda function

        if(hooks.containsKey(klass)) {
            hooks.get(klass).add(fn);
        } else {
            hooks.put(klass, new ArrayList<>(fn));
            hooks.get(klass).add(fn);
        }
    }
}

public static void fire(Event event) {
    ArrayList<Consumer<? extends Event>> classHooks = hooks.get(event.getClass());
    if(classHooks == null) {
        return;
    }

    for(Consumer c : classHooks) {
        c.accept(event);
    }
}
```

I tried a few things but couldn't find a way to make this work.

Comment: you could do it differently, store the "type" (an enum for example) inside the `Event` (if it's an interface, force everyone to implement it), and store these in an EnumMap. So instead of `hooks.get(event.getClass())`, you could do `hooks.get(event.getType)`, where `getType` would return an enum instance

Answer (score 0):

You will need to abandon your nifty idea of registering multiple consumers at once, and register them one at a time, supplying the event class for each one of them. Here is how to do it in a type-safe way:

```
public static <E extends Event> void hook( Class<E> eventClass,
        Consumer<E> consumer );
```